# Disparity between the std::deque and std::vector range constructors

Tags: c++, vector, deque, cpp-core-guidelines

This doesn't generate any warning at all and works as expected.

```
vector<float> vec_2(1024, -3.0f);   
vector<float> vec_3(vec_2.begin(), vec_2.end());
```

This, however, generates C26486 "Don't pass a pointer that may be invalid as a parameter to a function." warning. But still works.

```
deque<float> deque_2(1024, -3.0f);
deque<float> deque_3(deque_2.begin(), deque_2.end());
```

And I kinda get why the IDE would try to warn me about the implications of passing a pointer to an element of a non-contiguous container like `deque`. What I don't get is what's the point of this warning in this case in particular. `deque_2.begin()` will always return an iterator referencing the front-most element of the `deque`, `deque_2.end()` is pretty well-defined in its behavior as well.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with MSVC

Comment: Warning and error messages are unique to the compiler and not defined by the language. To get a useful answer, you should specify which compiler, which version and with which flags you produced these messages.

Comment: Current Clang and GCC versions do not warn (https://godbolt.org/z/JNGJB6)

Comment: MSVC does not warn either: https://godbolt.org/z/vQXUFN

Comment: Please specify any non-default compilation options used (if any). If non are used, then please modify your question with a [MCVE] that produces the warning you are asking about. The code you've shown does not produce any warnings.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This is not a default compiler warning, it's a warning generated under C++ core guidelines code analysis, that's why I put "C26486" before the actual message.

Comment: @BigTemp Then you may want to share how to enable or perform this analysis.

Comment: This looks like Static Analysis false positive. It may deserve feedback/report to the visual studio team, but I don't see how this is c++ vector/deque issue.

Comment: This feature came with one of the last updates for visual studio 2019 and reports many false positives. I think it is not very useful at the moment.

Comment: I like the VC++ code analysis, but from my experience the warnings for lifetime issues are often false positives.